# Excel: Concatenate Cells and Remove Duplicates

Tags: excel, duplicates, string-concatenation

how can I concatenate the Values in Cells `B1:K1` to receive the string in `A1`. Empty cells should be omitted. Is this possible using Excel commands or only with vba?

[image]

Comment: Maybe there's a more elegant solution but you could just use CONCATENATE, or an ampersand: =B1&C1&D1&E1&F1&G1&H1&I1&J1&K1

Comment: What Excel are you using?

Comment: If using >=Excel 2016 then you could try using `TEXTJOIN` [link](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/textjoin.php)

Comment: @Absinthe: I used concatenate already. However, that does not remove duplicates so that you get a string like a,b,a,c, , b.... which is not what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @Scott: using MS Office 2010 Prof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Office 365 Excel then you can use an Array form of TEXTJOIN:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,INDEX(1:1,,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF((IFERROR(MATCH(B1:K1,B1:K1,0)=COLUMN(B1:K1)-MIN(COLUMN(B1:K1))+1,0))*(B1:K1<>""),COLUMN(B1:K1)*{1;1}))))))
```

Being an array it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

If you do not have office 365 Excel you will need vba.  This UDF will mimic the TEXTJOIN.  Put it in a module attached to the workbook and use the formula as described above.

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```