# Concatenating repeating values in a single cell

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have some values in A1:K1 and the cells have various repeating numbers of single digits starting from 0 to 9.

`E.g, 0,0,0,1,1,2,2,4,5,5,7,7,...etc.` I need a formula to represent these values in a single cell M1 like this: `012457.`

So every value repeating or not should be represented with a single digit in the target cell without commas. I'd really appreciate a formula suggestion. Thanks.

Note: The end result should be numeric, so I can format it numerically in excel.

I am having problem with textjoin function suggested below, it doesn't work exactly the way I need when I want to do a conditional formatting on the end result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel: Concatenate Cells and Remove Duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47535683/excel-concatenate-cells-and-remove-duplicates)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Luuklag. I tried the method suggested in the link. it gives me the result I want. However, when I want to do a conditional format on the end result, I can't format it. because I guess it uses a textjoin function. and when I put double minus signs (--) in front of the formula, so excel sees it as a numeric value, if the result has "0", it disappears. and so it doesn't do what I want exactly.

Comment: To have your cells store leading zero's (which excel doesn't do by default) take a look here: https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/entering-leading-zeroes-in-excel/  In your case your format would requice 10 0's, as there are 10 possible numbers from 0 to 9

Comment: thanks.I tried that method now, It works on a value as in the example. but I couldn't make it work on the formula result. I still can't keep the leading zeros in the formula.